# How to plot points on a sphere in R

Tags: r, dictionary, plot

I am working on a project where I need to plot some points on a sphere. What I have are the longitude and latitude of each point, and a value at each point. For example,

```
longitude latitude value
123       23       1.3
75        -34      2.8
190       48       2.1
...
```

I want a plot like the following. I also want the size of the point to be proportional to the value in the data set. So 2.8 will have a bigger point and 1.3 will have a smaller point, etc. The world map is optional.

I wonder if there are any packages in R that can do this job? Any suggestions or codes are greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to project your point with a Mollweide projection? Or is it some other kind of projection that you want?

Comment: I googled 'r map projections' and got this link. http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/mapproj/html/mapproject.html It looks like it does what you want.

Comment: Additionnaly packages `sp`, `maptools` and `rgdal` are often used to deal with geographical data, with standard PROJ4 used for projections.

Comment: @plannapus Yes, Mollweide projection would be good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple example using `base` plot and packages `sp`, `rgdal` and `maptools`:

```
library(sp)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
xy <- data.frame(lon=c(-130,110,3,45),lat=c(60,-10,50,30)) #Some coordinates
value <- data.frame(value=c(1.5,0.8,2.3,2)) #Some values for the point size
df <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(xy,value,proj4string=CRS("+proj=lonlat"))
dfMoll <- spTransform(df, CRS("+proj=moll")) #Mollweide projection of the data
data(wrld_simpl) # A base world map
wrld_moll <- spTransform(wrld_simpl, CRS("+proj=moll")) # ... that we projects as well
plot(wrld_moll) #... and plot
points(dfMoll, cex=dfMoll$value, pch=20, col="red") #...with our data points
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the code. Can you point to me a good reference about projection in R (for example, reference on proj4string). I tried in the R help, but can't find much. Thanks.

Comment: proj4 is a standard not used by R only: you can find the official documentation [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/WikiStart#Documentation) and documentation for some of the most used projections [here](http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/proj_list/). The [R Tag](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/r/info) on [gis.SE] is also a nice ressource for cartography in R.

Comment: Additionnaly, [this website](http://geography.uoregon.edu/GeogR/), [this intro to package sp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/intro_sp.pdf) and [spacedman's cheatsheet](http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~rowlings/Teaching/UseR2012/cheatsheet.html) are definitely useful to dive in the subject.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe a way to do it with `ggplot2` :

```
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data=world,aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), fill=NA,colour="black") +
  geom_point(data=d, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, size=value), color="red") +
  coord_map("mollweide")
```

This gives the following map, with some glitches unfortunately :

[image]

You can use `coord_map` without drawing a map, by the way :

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=d, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, size=value), color="red") +
  coord_map("mollweide")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Look at the mapproj package.  It will do various map projections for you.  It does not do the plotting, but rather projects the points for you to then pass to the function of your choice.